# How do I increment the name of the log file in bash for each command?

Tags: bash

I'm fairly new to bash scripting but I'm really trying to learn as much as I can. I have a script written but am having a couple of different issues. 1. I want the script to continue to run if the user answers "y" to run the script again. 2. I also want the script to output a file but increment the file name by 1. This is the script I'm using:

```
#Whois commands
echo "Whois Scan Starting"
echo ""
echo "Please enter a domain name for a Whois lookup"
read dn
whois "$dn" > /root/Desktop/$client/Whois/whois.txt
read -rsp $'All done. Press enter to continue...\n'
read -p "Would you like to do another Whois lookup? [yn]" answer
if [[ $answer = y ]] ; then
#run the command
echo "Please enter a domain name for a Whois lookup"
read dn
whois "$dn" > /root/Desktop/$client/Whois/whois2.txt
read -rsp $'All done. Press enter to continue...\n'
fi
```

I'm guessing I need to use a while loop but I've tried a few different times but can't get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

To keep asking, use a `while true` loop. When the user answers no, use `break` to end the loop.

For the incrementing filename, set a variable to the number, and increment it after writing each file.

```
filenum=1
...
whois "$dn" > /root/Desktop/$client/Whois/whois$filename.txt
let filename=filenum+1
```